# What does baking a method means?

Tags: c#, stack-trace

I was reading this post here on [micro ORM](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/03/30/How+I+learned+to+stop+worrying+and+write+my+own+ORM) used on SO.

The author showed this stack-trace:

```
System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.Compile
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.GetReaderFactory
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Compile
System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices+DeferredSourceFactory`1.ExecuteKeyQuery
System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices+DeferredSourceFactory`1.Execute
System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault
System.Data.Linq.EntityRef`1.get_Entity
```

Then said:

> In the trace above you can see that 'EntityRef' is baking a method, which is not a problem, unless it is happening 100s of times a second.

Could someone explain the stack-trace in relation to what he meant by "baking a method" and why it would be a performance problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do something like:

```
int[] items = whatever;
IEnumerable<int> query = from item in items where item % 2 == 0 select item;
```

then the compiler turns that into something like:

```
static bool Predicate(int item) { return item % 2 == 0; }
...
IEnumerable<int> query = Enumerable.Where<int>(items, new Func<int, bool> (Predicate));
```

That is, the compiler generates the IL for the method. When you build the query object at runtime, the object returned by Where holds on to a delegate to the predicate, and executes the predicate when necessary.

But it is possible to build *the IL for the delegate* at runtime if you want to. What you do is persist the body of the predicate as an *expression tree*. At runtime the expression tree can dynamically compile itself into brand-new IL; basically we start up a very simplified compiler that knows how to generate IL for expression trees. That way you can change the details of the predicate at runtime and recompile the predicate without having to recompile the whole program.

The author of that comment is using "baking" as a slang for "dynamic lightweight code generation".

Comment: Thanks, could you give an example or explain a circumstance in why the expression tree would need to recompile at runtime? For example, in your example, is there any part of that which would recompile at runtime?

Comment: @Lolcoder: Suppose you obtained the details of the query from the user, because, say, they typed in the keyword they wanted to search on, or whether they wanted to perform a filter, or an order, or whatever. You might then want to build the predicate dynamically rather than having the compiler build it for you. The other common use case is when the expression tree is being turned into not a delegate, but bona fide SQL statements that are then transmitted to a back end database.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to creating a method dynamically at run time, for example by using an expression tree.  Compiling the expression tree to a method and returning a delegate for the compiled method could be called "baking" the method.

Comment: how do you know that from the stacktrace? just the 1st line of it saying DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate?

Comment: @Lolcoder I'm not saying that this stack trace specifically is operating with or on an expression tree.  I'm speaking generally about my understanding of the term "bake a method".  You could do it by emitting IL code; you could do it using an expression tree; and there may well be other ways to do it.  Or were you asking generally how does one know that the stack trace indicates "baking"?  That's evident from the calls to `Compile` and `CreateDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fancy way of saying that they're emitting dynamic code using Refrection.Emit. A notoriously slow process.

Comment: @Lolcoder: The performance hit is using dynamic lightweight code gen, the code for which is in the Reflection namespace.